# Why does inner class have to specify Outer.this.remove(int)?

Tags: java

Why does an inner class *sometimes* have to explicitly specify the outer class instance in order to call an outer class method for which there is no matching method in the inner class?

Example:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Outer {
    void remove(int index) {}

    private class Inner implements Iterator {
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Object next() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            remove(0); // error: remove() in Inner cannot be applied to (int)
            Outer.this.remove(0); // ok
        }
    }
}
```

My original, failed attempt at an example shows that this disambiguation is *not* generally required:

```
public class Outer {
  private Object field;

  void method() {}

  private class Inner {
    void innerMethod() {
      if(field == null) {
        method(); // ok
        Outer.this.method(); // ok
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Because no class has knowledge of its outside environment.  Why would it?

Comment: You need the `Outer` disambiguation to indicate that you're not calling a method within the inner class's boundaries.

Comment: @RobertHarvey An inner class has knowledge of its outside environment in the form of an implicit reference to the enclosing class.  I'm wondering why it can use this knowlege for fields but not methods.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, but *why*?  Why is there any ambiguity if no method of the inner class matches the signature of the method being called, but a method in the outer class does?

Comment: Since I'm not the language designers, anything I say would be speculation, but this is the way I would do it.  Requiring the disambiguation means I only need to bind methods *directly,* within the same class; I don't have to hunt for other methods *outside the class boundaries* to bind.  Under ordinary circumstances, when you're composing with other objects, you still have to refer to the other object when calling a method on that object, so I don't see how this is any different.

Comment: Further, requiring this disambiguation forces you to write the call in a way that is *crystal-clear;* it is readily apparent to the programmers who read the code after you exactly what is happening.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The disambiguation is actually misleading because if a subclass of `Outer` overrides `method()`, `Inner` will call the override.  The disambiguation deceptively looks like "call this class's implementation of `method()`", which you cannot actually write.

Comment: That is always true, whether you're disambiguating the call or not.  The override rules aren't going to change just because you're disambiguating the method call to the correct class.

Comment: @RobertHarvey None of this addresses why the disambiguation is necessary.

Comment: It's not necessary at all.  The Java designers could have chosen to do it your way; they just decided not to.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Now you're just being pedantic.  Do I really need to explicitly define "necessary" as "required by the compiler"?

Comment: It's required by the compiler because the Java designers decided that's how it's going to work.  If you're not going to provide a mechanism by which you can write a non-disambiguated call, then it makes sense for the compiler to prohibit such a call.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I find it highly improbable that they did so arbitrarily or accidentally.  If you genuinely think there is no real reason, why don't you run that answer up the flagpole and see who salutes?

Comment: Have you actually tried removing the `Outer.this` reference? What error message do you get when compiling?

Comment: @kdgregory See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

The entire premise of the question is wrong. If you remove the `Outer.this` it will compile as normal. You don't have to qualify method access if there is no ambiguity. The question you linked asked specifically about what to do if both the inner and outer class have a method with *the same signature* and how to decide which method to call (it then gives the inner by default, outer by explicit qualification)

Comment: Mea culpa.  I added an example that more closely matches the real code that prompted the question, thereby narrowing the premise.

Comment: Ah, that is indeed true and a more interesting question. I'll try to find something about the issue. Not sure what's the SE policy here is, since your edit pretty much invalidated a perfectly sound answer to the original question...

Answer (score 3):

This is an opinion rather than an answer, as I am not and have not been part of the Java development team. But an opinion with JLS references.

I think it is an accident, caused by an unnecessarily over-precise specification. In other words, a *de facto* bug but *de jure* intended behavior.

The specification in question is [JLS 15.12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12), *Method Invocation Expressions*, and in particular [JLS 15.12.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12), *Compile-Time Step 1: Determine Class or Interface to Search*:

> The first step in processing a method invocation at compile time is to figure out the name of the method to be invoked and which class or interface to search for definitions of methods of that name.

Note that the specification uses the term "name" rather than "signature."

> If the Identifier appears in the scope of a visible method declaration with that name (§6.3, §6.4.1), then: 
>   If there is an enclosing type declaration of which that method is a member, let T be the innermost such type declaration. The class or interface to search is T.

Note the terminology "innermost such type declaration." As I read this, once the declaring type has been selected, then it is the *only* type that will be searched for methods of the given name.

So, to apply this:

- In your original example, you used two different names. The compiler identified that the name was declared in the enclosing class, and there was no need to use disambiguation.
- In the linked example, the method signatures are the same. This would require disambiguation even if the spec were different.
- In your final example, the method *name* appears in the inner class, so the compiler looks to that class for resolution. However, since the inner class doesn't define the correct *signature*, it is unable to resolve the method without disambiguation.

So, there you have behavior. As for reason, unless [@BrianGoetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz) or another  person with personal knowledge decides to answer, we'll all just have to speculate.

Comment: The technical explanation is (IMO) correct.  The *why* is speculation, and I disagree that it was an "accident".  I think that the real reason is that if they did this, is that without the "innermost" clause, there is  too much linguistic complexity (for the spec and compiler writers) and the rules for method resolution are even harder for the programmer to grasp.